# Why does Ctrl-S disable the save button on Azure blob storage file editor?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

When you edit a file in Azure blob storage the 'save' icon turns blue, indicating you have changes to be saved. However if you press Ctrl-S, it turns grey and your changes are not saved.
If you manually click the save button, you get a message with a green tick saying 'Saved'.

Why does Ctrl-S not only save the changes to the file, but also disable it from being pressed? I'm not sure if this is a unintended bug or a feature i'm unaware of.

Thanks.

Edit: I am useing the Azure Web portal to edit these blob files. 
[image]

Comment: Not sure what "save" icon you're referring to, or which app you're using for editing blobs. Please edit your question for clarity.

Comment: Thanks, I have added a picture which hopefully adds some clarity. I am editing the content of a file within blob storage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I think this should be a bug(or it's not supported since it is not listed [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/azure-portal-keyboard-shortcuts)).

I use the develop tool(press F12 button) of Edge browser for the debug.

**When** directly click the `Save` button after editing the content, there're 2 main requests being called. The first one is `PUT request`, which is used to save the updated content; the 2nd one is the `POST request`, which is used to grey out the "Save" button. Please refer to the screenshot as below:

[image]

**When** use the `ctrl + s` key-combination, there is only the `POST request`, which is used to grey out the "Save" button. But the `PUT request`(which is used to save the updated content) is never called. Please refer to the screenshot as below:

[image]

I have submitted this issue to the support team, and I will keep the post updated if there is any feedback.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth research - I thought it was probably a bug but it's nice to have it officially raised. I look forward to being able to Ctrl-S soon :)